# Calculating Estimated Time Left in Loop (When iteration number is very big and time required for each iteration is very low)

Tags: c#, time

I'm trying to calculate total time remaining of a for loop. Total number of iterations can be more than ~1010000000. Total time required for doing "Real job done here" is much lower than a second and it doesnt change much. When i use my current solution time remaining increases for a long time and than starts to decrease.

I'm looking for a better solution. What can i do?

```
long totalTiles = ((((rightBottom.X) - (topLeft.X)) + 1) * (((rightBottom.Y) - (topLeft.Y)) + 1));
long currentTileProccessed = 0;

DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

for (long x = (topLeft.X); x <= (rightBottom.X); x++)
{
    for (long y = (topLeft.Y); y <= (rightBottom.Y); y++)
    {
        **//Real job done here//**

        TimeSpan timeRemaining = TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).Ticks * (totalTiles - (currentTileProccessed + 1)) / (currentTileProccessed + 1));

        this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate () {
            EstimatedTimeLeft_TextBlock.Text = "Days : " + timeRemaining.Days.ToString("D2") + ", Hours : " + timeRemaining.Hours.ToString("D2") + ", Minutes :" + timeRemaining.Minutes.ToString("D2") + ", Seconds :" + timeRemaining.Seconds.ToString("D2");
        });

        currentTileProccessed++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know that your going to get much better than that unless you can feed in additional knowledge (like "Initializing takes a little longer, so I'll adjust the time based on that").  Unrelated, have you considered using `Parallel.For`?  Assuming, of course, that your process is conducive to that.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am using Stopwatch from System.Diagnostics to determine the average time for the last 100 tasks, which I multiply against the total expected number of tasks minus the number already run.

NOTE: Remaining time can still increase, if suddenly the last 100 tasks start running slower than the previous 10k, this will readjust your remaining time to match the recent runs.

```
long totalTiles = ((((rightBottom.X) - (topLeft.X)) + 1) * (((rightBottom.Y) - (topLeft.Y)) + 1));
long currentTileProccessed = 0;

Queue<long> taskTimes = new Queue<long>();
int taskTimeHistoryLimit = 100;

long taskTotal = (rightBottom.X - topLeft.X) * (rightBottom.Y - topLeft.Y);

Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();


long index = 0;
for (long x = (topLeft.X); x <= (rightBottom.X); x++)
{
    for (long y = (topLeft.Y); y <= (rightBottom.Y); y++)
    {
        index++;
        watch.Start();
        //Real job done here//
        watch.Stop();
        taskTimes.Enqueue(watch.ElapsedTicks);
        watch.Reset();
        while (taskTimes.Count > taskTimeHistoryLimit)
        {
            taskTimes.Dequeue();
        }
        TimeSpan timeRemaining = new TimeSpan((taskTotal - index) * (long)taskTimes.Average());

        this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate () {
            EstimatedTimeLeft_TextBlock.Text = "Days : " + timeRemaining.Days.ToString("D2") + ", Hours : " + timeRemaining.Hours.ToString("D2") + ", Minutes :" + timeRemaining.Minutes.ToString("D2") + ", Seconds :" + timeRemaining.Seconds.ToString("D2");
        });
    }
}
```